# Reusing a Yii2 query

Tags: php, yii2

Am trying to reuse a query but it fails.

In my method I have:

```
public function getPacked($from, $to){
    $initquery = RealTimeTblTrucks::find()
        ->leftJoin('tbl_truck_history','tbl_truck_history.truck_id=tbl_trucks.id')
        ->where(["between","tbl_truck_history.created_at",$from,$to])
        ->andWhere(["tbl_truck_history.status"=>20]);

    $data = [];
    $data[SELF] =$initquery
        ->andWhere(["tbl_trucks.truck_category"=>28])
        ->count();

    $data[NORMAL] = $initquery->andWhere(["tbl_trucks.truck_category"=>27])
        ->count();
    $data[BULKER]  = $initquery->andWhere(['in', 'tbl_trucks.truck_category', [26,34]])
        ->count();

    return $data;
}
```

Now the first (`$data[SELF]`) returns the correct information but the next ones `NORMAL` and `BULKER` didn't return the correct information.

When I check on the raw query I can see that the last two are affected by the first one such that the new query at `$data[NORMAL]` contains a check for `truck_category = 20` which should only be executed on the first array item (`SELF`).

How to refactor this to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Advantage of [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) over creation a new object, is that, all properties will be copied into the new object instead of resetting them. This is quite useful when you use query builder.

```
public function getPacked($from, $to) {

   $initquery = RealTimeTblTrucks::find()
    ->leftJoin('tbl_truck_history','tbl_truck_history.truck_id=tbl_trucks.id')
    ->where(["between","tbl_truck_history.created_at",$from,$to])
    ->andWhere(["tbl_truck_history.status"=>20]);

   $data = [];
   $querySelf = clone $initquery;
   $data[SELF] = $querySelf
    ->andWhere(["tbl_trucks.truck_category"=>28])
    ->count();

   $queryNormal = clone $initquery;
   $data[NORMAL] = $queryNormal->andWhere(["tbl_trucks.truck_category"=>27])
    ->count();

   $queryBulker = clone $initquery;
   $data[BULKER]  = $queryBulker->andWhere(['in', 'tbl_trucks.truck_category', [26,34]])
    ->count();

   return $data;
}
```

Refer [Yii2 clone detail](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-component#__clone()-detail)

Comment: You can use `(clone $initquery)->andWhere(...)` as a shortcut.